# Why is there a gap in my layout?

Tags: html, css

Its been a few hours now and I cannot figure out why there is a gap in my layout.

**picture:** [image]

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4123377/gap.png

**html:** http://pastebin.com/7WktN5EA

**css:** http://pastebin.com/Fj8rukJ8

The button is "#login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **#login ul ul** seems to be setting a **top** value of 50, which applies to the first element as well as all the others - so the first element seems to be causing the gap.

```
#login ul ul {
    background-image: url(../assets/loggeddarkfill.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; /* this guy */
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The right value is 40px - that will get rid of the gap and position the list like you want it.

Comment: I love you too! also a genius!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to adjust the **top** value for **#login ul ul**.